# Calculate difference in percent grouped on Country and Date

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I already can calculate difference in percent grouped by date,

```
let t = (datatable(Value:int, Date:datetime, Сountry:string) 
[1000, '2018-01-01', "USA",    // 1 Jan == 100% 
 2000, '2018-01-01', "Poland", // this 100% also because grouped by Date 
 3000, '2018-01-02', "USA",    // 2 Jan == 233% because compared with 1 Jan
 4000, '2018-01-02', "Poland", // 233% also
]);
```

**let val_2018 = toscalar(t | where Date >= datetime(2018-01-01) and Date < datetime(2018-01-02)  | summarize sum(Value));
t
| summarize percent = 100.0 * sum(Value) / val_2018 by Date**

So i need to get 4 records like these:

```
1 Jan, USA, 100%
1 Jan, Poland, 100%
2 Jan, USA, 300%
2 Jan, Poland, 200%
```

but how add grouping by country as well? As i understood need to add "by Сountry" in all "summarize" but toscalar can't have "by" after "summarize" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [`prev()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction) and [`iff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ifffunction) functions.

For example:

```
datatable(['value']: int, ['date']: datetime, ['country']: string) [
    1000, datetime(2018-01-01), "USA",   
    2000, datetime(2018-01-01), "Poland",
    3000, datetime(2018-01-02), "USA",   
    4000, datetime(2018-01-02), "Poland",
]
| order by country asc, ['date'] asc
| extend percentage = iff(
    prev(country) == country,
    100.0 * value / prev(value),
    100.0)
```

| value | date | country | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Poland | 100 |
| 4000 | 2018-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | Poland | 200 |
| 1000 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | USA | 100 |
| 3000 | 2018-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | USA | 300 |

Comment: This is good but i need to keep filtering date, because i need filter date by Year, Day, Quarter, Week, etc. So can we put this where Date >= datetime(2018-01-01) and Date < datetime(2018-01-02) somehow, please?)

Comment: your intention isn't clear (to me). it may be helpful if you can provide a data set _before_ filtering was applied to it, and the expected output that matches it (including a description of the filtering logic)

Comment: I need devide all value on value from some date, so thats why i need keep filtering. 
Your code is perfrect , but prev can't contain variabale, by the way i need just Date, Percent and Country (without Value in output). Help please :-)
code should something like that

`let val_2018 = toscalar(t | where Date == datetime(2018-01-01) | summarize sum(Value));
t | order by Country asc, Date asc
  | extend percentage = iff(
    prev(Country) == Country,
    100.0 * Value / prev(val_2018),
    100.0)`

Comment: it's not clear why if `val_2018` is calculated once, why are you trying to divide by `prev(val_2018)`. as mentioned above, and in order to help you clarify the problem you're trying to solve, i would recommend you provide a meaningful sample data set (using the `datatable` operator) and the expected output for it.

Comment: ok, thanks.
Is it posible to set Country which enumerated into toscalar?
`toscalar(t | where Date == datetime(2018-01-01) and **set this(enumerated) country instead getting all records from 1 Jan** | summarize sum(Value))` ?

Comment: sorry, your question is still not clear to me. please see my repeated recommendations above, on how to present your question in a clearer way.

Comment: yeah this a bit difficult to explain, sorry. The problem is that i get sum of all records on 1 Jan... so i need get sum for one country instead getting sum for all countries 
a need something like this, but i can have a lot of countries)
 toscalar(t | where Date == datetime(2018-01-01) and  **Country == "USA"** | summarize sum(Value));
Some function, maybe? for set just one country in smart way

Comment: tried that 
`let val_2018 = (CountryName:string) { toscalar(t | where Date == datetime(2018-01-01) and  Country == CountryName | summarize sum(Value))};
t | serialize| order by Date asc| extend percent = 100.0 * row_cumsum(Value) / val_2018(Country)`
but output is wrong in some reason

Comment: solved via join | join kind=inner (
    t
    | where year_date >= datetime(2022-01-01) and year_date < datetime(2023-01-01)
    |summarize _value1 = sum(value) by _key0=bin(startofyear(year_date), 1), _key1=country_description
) on $left.key1 == $right._key1

But anyway thanks for help :)